# Minimum area geometric cover for a set of line segments

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

The problem I am trying to solve is:

Given a set of M points on a plane where circles can be centered and a set of N line segments which need to be covered by the circles, find the minimum area circle cover for the line segments. That is, find the radii of the circles and the centers (chosen from the M points) such that all the N line segments are covered and the total area of the circles is minimized.

Note that a line segment is covered if no part of it is OUTSIDE a circle.

Any pointers to papers or code or approximation algorithms would be great.

Comment: I believe your problem is NP-hard, so you are going to have to settle for approximation algorithms.

Comment: As a suggested heuristic - find the point from the possible center set that is nearest the centroid of all the line segment endpoints, and use that as the center. The radius of the circle would be the distance from that center to the farthest line segment endpoint. That should cover most cases, but I can't prove that it'll always give an optimal answer. In particular, if you have one line segment that is really far away from all the others, it may significantly skew things.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. The possible centers of the circles are already given. I want to place circles at those centers and select their radii such that the segments are covered.

Comment: Ah... I think I misunderstood the question - on first reading it sounded like you wanted a single circle that was constrained to have its center in one of a limited set of positions... Having multiple circles does make this more difficult - sounds like a good match for a dynamic programming approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Just realized that the original approach (moved to the end) probably doesn't cover the case where a line segment is best covered by multiple circles very well. So I think it's better to iterate points instead of line segments, cutting the line segments down at the circle boundaries:

1. Find the "worst" point, i.e. the point requiring the largest additional circle area for its best circle center option with the corresponding line segment at least partially in the circle. Construct / extend the corresponding circle.
2. Remove fully covered line segments from the set and cut partially covered segments at the circle boundary.
3. Iterate until no more line segments remain.

The main idea is to keep doing what's necessary in any case. How are overlapping circles counted? Do the areas add up, or are they merged? When going back to step one in later iterations, some kind of cost heuristics will probably be able to improve the result...

The original suggestion was:

1. Find the "worst" line segment, i.e. the line segment requiring the largest circle for any of the circle center options and construct the corresponding circle.
2. Remove covered line segments from the set.
3. Iterate until no more line segments remain.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. I came up with covering each line segment at a time with the minimum area cover using a greedy approach - i.e. start covering with the smallest circle and work up on the radii until the line segment is completely covered. Then take the union of the result. May not work for overlapping circles though.

Comment: To answer your question: Overlapping circles are added up in cost.

Comment: After thinking about this some more, some form of a* might be what you need for an optimal solution (with covering as much as possible early) -- it now seems relatively easy to construct an example where the proposed heuristic wouldn't work that well. For this, something to calculating a lower bound on the remaining cost might be useful....

Comment: Thanks but I am not familiar with a*. Could you point me at some references? I liked your approach. Can you describe a situation where it would fail? I was thinking of discretizing the possible radii and just trying all combinations to come up with an optimum but the running time is horrendous.

Comment: The situation where I think it certainly wouldn't be optimal is where you have the segments clustered -- and just one end point being closer to an "outside" point. I'd implement it anyway, as the main work will be in the helpers you'll need in any case (cut a circle out of the set of segments). A*: The wikipedia description seems readable, but the link doesn't work because of the star. Search for "A*_search_algorithm" there.

Comment: I modified your suggested approach as follows:   Find the worst line, i.e. the line requiring the largest additional
    circle area for its best circle center option with the corresponding
    line segment entirely in the circle.

    Construct / extend the corresponding circle.

    Remove fully covered line segments from the set and cut partially
    covered segments at the circle boundary.  

    Remove the center from the set of possible centers.
    
    Iterate until no more line segments remain.

Comment: The reason I had to modify it was in order to ensure termination. I have implemented the algorithm in python.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Were you able to measure how well the algorithm performs? Why not post the implementation as a gist (or similar), might encourage people to look into improving it? Wrt termination: you'd need to make sure the line segment has at least two separate points in the circle in step 1, ensuring actual progress.

Comment: No progress over thanksgiving. Will post a gist after I have tested things some more. I think some local optimization (moving fragments between adjoining segments) could help.

Comment: Any idea what the complexity of an optimum solution for the original problem would be? (i.e. np-complete or P-space). Something tells me it is worse than np complete because of the radii being continuous variables.

Answer (score -1):

I just released some code to implement the suggested algorithm here:

https://github.com/usnistgov/esc-antenna-cover